# How the Deep Learning benchmark performed for 16 bit and for 8 bit fixed point precision?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, benchmarking

Can Alexnet or Google net run with 16 bit and for 8 bit fixed point precision? Assume i am using caffe framework.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Caffe fork called [Ristretto](http://lepsucd.com/?page_id=621) that can quantize existing trained neural networks.

But I am not sure whether performing inference in Caffe is possible with "true" 16-bit quantization. Precisely, the parameters and activations of the NN can be 16 or 8 bits alright, but the intermediate accumulations of values (say, when doing sum of products for convolutions) might still be performed in 32 float registers (which are then rounded and clipped to 16 or 8 bits). So I wouldn't call it a 100% "true" 16- or 8-bit implementation. But it still gives an idea about how the accuracy would drop when switching to a lower bit quantization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even 8-bit precision has shown effective for both of those networks, although there can be a minor loss of accuracy.  16-bit seems to be quite sufficient to the classification tasks.